# Phalcon Micro - Secure Routes

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I've just started trying out Phalcon Micro for my RestAPI's.

Everything is working well, however I can't seem to figure out how to secure some routes, but not others.

Has anyone had any experience in this area? - I've come from Slim where I can just pass functions in the actual route definitions.

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this, you can use `beforeMatch()` on your route, as you are used to with Slim.

```
$router->add('/koshnitsa', 'Basket::index')->setName('basket')->beforeMatch(
    function ($uri, $route) {
        // Replace with your conditions
        if ($https) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

You can even make your own filter, read more in [**the docs**](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.2/reference/routing.html#match-callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use more generic approach with events or middleware:

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/micro.html#micro-application-events
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/micro.html#middleware-events